# The fastest GZIP decompress library in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, performance, zip, gzip

Which .NET library has the fastest decompress performance (in terms of throughput)?

There are quite a few libraries out there...

- [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)
- [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)
- [Xceed Zip for .NET](http://xceed.com/Zip_NET_Intro.html)
- [SevenZipLib](http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/)
- [SharpZipLib | community sponsor of Xceed Zip for .NET](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)

...and I expect there are more I haven't listed.

Has anyone seen a benchmark of the throughput performance of these GZIP libraries? I'm interested in decompression throughput, but I'd like to see the results for compression too.

Comment: Have no clue about the benchmarks you are looking for, but there is is also SharpZipLib http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

Comment: The standalone 7-zip executable is usually seen as being right at the top in terms of speed... and SevenZipLib is simple a .Net wrapper of it, so I'd go for that one. I have no real benchmarks though.

Comment: Why is this important?  It is always a fraction of the I/O time needed to obtain the stream.

Comment: Does it have to be a 100% pure .NET solution or are you willing to use anything that you can access from .NET?

Comment: `@Hans Passant:` It's important because I have 1000s of multi-GB files I need to decompress. Throughput will NOT be a fraction of the I/O time needed to obtain the stream.

Comment: `@Marnix van Valen:` I'm willing to use any solution that is accessible from .NET... What do you have in mind?

Comment: @Rudiger: The number and size of your files makes no difference to Hans Passant's argument.  The only thing that would make a difference is if you were reading the files off an unusually fast storage medium like SSD or a wide RAID.  Any non-cretinous implementation of deflate on a modern CPU will be starved for input at a single regular HDD's read rate.  (You know the OS reads the next block of input while the current block is being decompressed, right?  Processing and read times are not additive.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: We have a pretty "wide" RAID setup; single-digit gigabytes per second... Enough for disks to not necessarily be the bottle-neck. I was kind of assuming that the fastest GZIP on one disk would be the fastest across a cluster when I scale it out...

Comment: @Rudiger, what's your performance difference between just reading the file and discarding vs reading, decompressing, and discarding?  That will tell you if decompression is truly worth optimizing in this scenario.

Comment: @Rudiger: In that case your I/O throughput might well exceed the CPU throughput.  I did some quick searches hoping to find memory-to-memory decompression throughput measurements for gzip decompression and didn't find any, but was surprised to see evidence that compression *is* still CPU-bound.  I know gzip decompression is much less CPU-intensive but it's possible I overstated my case earlier ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've have had good performance with SevenZipLib for very large files, but I was using the native 7zip format and highly compressible content.  If you're using content that won't have a high compression ratio, then your throughput will vary greatly compared to some of the benchmarks you can find for these libraries.

Answer (score 15):

I found problems with Microsoft's GZipStream implementation not being able to read certain gzip files, so I have been testing a few libraries.

This is a basic test I adapted for you to run, tweak, and decide:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Ionic.Zlib;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip;

namespace ZipTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ZipTests
    {
        MemoryStream input, compressed, decompressed;
        Stream compressor;
        int inputSize;
        Stopwatch timer;

        public ZipTests()
        {
            string testFile = "TestFile.pdf";
            using(var file = File.OpenRead(testFile))
            {
                inputSize = (int)file.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("Reading " + inputSize + " from " + testFile);
                var ms = new MemoryStream(inputSize);
                file.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, inputSize);
                ms.Position = 0;
                input = ms;
            }
            compressed = new MemoryStream();
        }

        void StartCompression()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Using " + compressor.GetType() + ":");
            GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced); // Start fresh
            timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }

        public void EndCompression()
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("  took " + timer.Elapsed
                + " to compress " + inputSize.ToString("#,0") + " bytes into "
                + compressed.Length.ToString("#,0"));
            decompressed = new MemoryStream(inputSize);
            compressed.Position = 0; // Rewind!
            timer.Restart();
        }

        public void AfterDecompression()
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("  then " + timer.Elapsed + " to decompress.");
            Assert.AreEqual(inputSize, decompressed.Length);
            Assert.AreEqual(input.GetBuffer(), decompressed.GetBuffer());
            input.Dispose();
            compressed.Dispose();
            decompressed.Dispose();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestGZipStream()
        {
            compressor = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(compressed, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, true);
            StartCompression();
            compressor.Write(input.GetBuffer(), 0, inputSize);
            compressor.Close();

            EndCompression();

            var decompressor = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(compressed, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
            decompressor.CopyTo(decompressed);

            AfterDecompression();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestDotNetZip()
        {
            compressor = new Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(compressed, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Compress, true);
            StartCompression();
            compressor.Write(input.GetBuffer(), 0, inputSize);
            compressor.Close();

            EndCompression();

            var decompressor = new Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(compressed,
                                    Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
            decompressor.CopyTo(decompressed);

            AfterDecompression();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSharpZlib()
        {
            compressor = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipOutputStream(compressed)
            { IsStreamOwner = false };
            StartCompression();
            compressor.Write(input.GetBuffer(), 0, inputSize);
            compressor.Close();

            EndCompression();

            var decompressor = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipInputStream(compressed);
            decompressor.CopyTo(decompressed);

            AfterDecompression();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running CLR version " + Environment.Version +
                " on " + Environment.OSVersion);
            Assert.AreEqual(1,1); // Preload NUnit
            new ZipTests().TestGZipStream();
            new ZipTests().TestDotNetZip();
            new ZipTests().TestSharpZlib();
        }
    }
}
```

And the result *in the system I am currently running* (Mono on Linux), is as follows:

```
Running Mono CLR version 4.0.30319.1 on Unix 3.2.0.29
Reading 37711561 from /home/agustin/Incoming/ZipTests/TestFile.pdf
Using System.IO.Compression.GZipStream:
  took 00:00:03.3058572 to compress 37,711,561 bytes into 33,438,894
  then 00:00:00.5331546 to decompress.
Reading 37711561 from /home/agustin/Incoming/ZipTests/TestFile.pdf
Using Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream:
  took 00:00:08.9531478 to compress 37,711,561 bytes into 33,437,891
  then 00:00:01.8047543 to decompress.
Reading 37711561 from /home/agustin/Incoming/ZipTests/TestFile.pdf
Using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipOutputStream:
  took 00:00:07.4982231 to compress 37,711,561 bytes into 33,431,962
  then 00:00:02.4157496 to decompress.
```

Be warned that this is Mono's GZIP, and Microsoft's version will give its own results (and as I mentioned, just can't handle any gzip you give it)

This is what I got on a windows system:

```
Running CLR version 4.0.30319.1 on Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3
Reading 37711561 from TestFile.pdf
Using System.IO.Compression.GZipStream:
  took 00:00:03.3557061 to compress 37.711.561 bytes into 36.228.969
  then 00:00:00.7079438 to decompress.
Reading 37711561 from TestFile.pdf
Using Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream:
  took 00:00:23.4180958 to compress 37.711.561 bytes into 33.437.891
  then 00:00:03.5955664 to decompress.
Reading 37711561 from TestFile.pdf
Using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip.GZipOutputStream:
  took 00:00:09.9157130 to compress 37.711.561 bytes into 33.431.962
  then 00:00:03.0983499 to decompress.
```

It is easy enough to add more tests...

Comment: can you try sevenzipsharp
http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: System.IO.Compression looks pretty good if we just look at the times. But it looks less so if we look at the produced sizes. Then again both measurements could be atypical and a result of your particular input. This doesn't really tell us much...

Answer (score 4):

Compression performance benchmarks vary based on the size of streams being compressed and the precise content.  If this is a particularly important performance bottleneck for you then it'd be worth your time to write a sample app using each library and running tests with your real files.

Comment: Exactly, compression performance varies based on datatype in question.