# Parallel GZip Decompression of Log Files - Tweaking MaxDegreeOfParallelism for the Highest Throughput

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

We have up to 30 GB of GZipped log files per day. Each file holds 100.000 lines and is between 6 and 8 MB when compressed. The simplified code in which the parsing logic has been stripped out, utilises the Parallel.ForEach loop.

The maximum number of lines processed peaks at MaxDegreeOfParallelism of 8 on the two-NUMA node, 32 logical CPU box (Intel Xeon E7-2820 @ 2 GHz):

```cs
using System;

using System.Collections.Concurrent;

using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelLineCount
{
    public class ScriptMain
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            int    maxMaxDOP      = (args.Length > 0) ? Convert.ToInt16(args[0]) : 2;
            string fileLocation   = (args.Length > 1) ? args[1] : "C:\\Temp\\SomeFiles" ;
            string filePattern    = (args.Length > 1) ? args[2] : "*2012-10-30.*.gz";
            string fileNamePrefix = (args.Length > 1) ? args[3] : "LineCounts";

            Console.WriteLine("Start:                 {0}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"));
            Console.WriteLine("Processing file(s):    {0}", filePattern);
            Console.WriteLine("Max MaxDOP to be used: {0}", maxMaxDOP.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("MaxDOP,FilesProcessed,ProcessingTime[ms],BytesProcessed,LinesRead,SomeBookLines,LinesPer[ms],BytesPer[ms]");

            for (int maxDOP = 1; maxDOP <= maxMaxDOP; maxDOP++)
            {

                // Construct ConcurrentStacks for resulting strings and counters
                ConcurrentStack<Int64> TotalLines = new ConcurrentStack<Int64>();
                ConcurrentStack<Int64> TotalSomeBookLines = new ConcurrentStack<Int64>();
                ConcurrentStack<Int64> TotalLength = new ConcurrentStack<Int64>();
                ConcurrentStack<int>   TotalFiles = new ConcurrentStack<int>();

                DateTime FullStartTime = DateTime.Now;

                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fileLocation, filePattern);

                var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDOP };

                //  Method signature: Parallel.ForEach(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body)
                Parallel.ForEach(files, options, currentFile =>
                    {
                        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
                        DateTime fileStartTime = DateTime.Now;

                        using (FileStream inFile = File.Open(fileLocation + "\\" + filename, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            Int64 lines = 0, someBookLines = 0, length = 0;
                            String line = "";

                            using (var reader = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress)))
                            {
                                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                                {
                                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                                    lines++; // total lines
                                    length += line.Length;  // total line length

                                    if (line.Contains("book")) someBookLines++; // some special lines that need to be parsed later
                                }

                                TotalLines.Push(lines); TotalSomeBookLines.Push(someBookLines); TotalLength.Push(length);
                                TotalFiles.Push(1); // silly way to count processed files :)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );

                TimeSpan runningTime = DateTime.Now - FullStartTime;

                // Console.WriteLine("MaxDOP,FilesProcessed,ProcessingTime[ms],BytesProcessed,LinesRead,SomeBookLines,LinesPer[ms],BytesPer[ms]");
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}",
                    maxDOP.ToString(),
                    TotalFiles.Sum().ToString(),
                    Convert.ToInt32(runningTime.TotalMilliseconds).ToString(),
                    TotalLength.Sum().ToString(),
                    TotalLines.Sum(),
                    TotalSomeBookLines.Sum().ToString(),
                    Convert.ToInt64(TotalLines.Sum() / runningTime.TotalMilliseconds).ToString(),
                    Convert.ToInt64(TotalLength.Sum() / runningTime.TotalMilliseconds).ToString());

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Finish:                " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a summary of the results, with a clear peak at MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8:

[image]

The CPU load (shown aggregated here, most of the load was on a single NUMA node, even when DOP was in 20 to 30 range):

[image]

The only way I've found to make CPU load cross 95% mark was to split the files across 4 different folders and execute the same command 4 times, each one targeting a subset of all files.

Can someone find a bottleneck?

Comment: Perhaps your filesystem is the limiting factor... as a test you can try loading the file into a memory stream and use that instead of the filestream...

Comment: You mean without decompression, plain load into memory? It's only 600 MB, and I hope that our storage is better than that :) Will test it and add to the question analysis.

Comment: Can you provide a table with (MaxDegreeOfParallelism, program run time) from 1 to 8?

Comment: It's already in the attached screenshot - would you need it in the text format?

Comment: No, thanks, ... just read the code, ... and skipped the analysis part :)

Comment: Is it a single mechanical disk you're reading from? That won't give you much parallelism.

Comment: 600MB of source files are all in cache. Disk is not touched.

Comment: @mceda why don't you just profile the app? Either use a tool or pause the debugger 10 times to see where it stops. That will tell you where threads are waiting.

Comment: @usr, I did use Visual Studio's Concurrency Analyser, but only on the workstation. Tomorrow I'll have results from the server and will update the question with a summary of today.

Comment: @mceda Interesting behaviour.  I tried to reproduce your results on one of my servers, using your sample.  I had little luck; my test was able to sustain 100% CPU usage for the duration of the test.

Since an I/O bottleneck seems unlikely based on previous responses, is there any chance that there is some constraint on processor affinity for the process or a low upper bound of threads available in the thread pool for the process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's likely that one problem is the small buffer size used by the default `FileStream` constructor. I suggest you use a larger input buffer. Such as:

```
using (FileStream infile = new FileStream(
    name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 65536))
```

The default buffer size is 4 kilobytes, which has the thread making many calls to the I/O subsystem to fill its buffer. A buffer of 64K means that you will make those calls much less frequently.

I've found that a buffer size of between 32K and 256K gives the best performance, with 64K being the "sweet spot" when I did some detailed testing a while back. A buffer size larger than 256K actually begins to reduce performance.

Also, although this is unlikely to have a major effect on performance, you probably should replace those `ConcurrentStack` instances with 64-bit integers and use `Interlocked.Add` or `Interlocked.Increment` to update them. It simplifies your code and removes the need to manage the collections.

Update:

Re-reading your problem description, I was struck by this statement:

> The only way I've found to make CPU load cross 95% mark was to split
>   the files across 4 different folders and execute the same command 4
>   times, each one targeting a subset of all files.

That, to me, points to a bottleneck in opening files. As though the OS is using a mutual exclusion lock on the directory. And even if all the data is in the cache and there's no physical I/O required, processes still have to wait on this lock. It's also possible that the file system is writing to the disk. Remember, it has to update the Last Access Time for a file whenever it's opened.

If I/O really is the bottleneck, then you might consider having a single thread that does nothing but load files and stuff them into a `BlockingCollection` or similar data structure so that the processing threads don't have to contend with each other for a lock on the directory. Your application becomes a producer/consumer application with one producer and N consumers.

Comment: I agree. I have seen this to be the reason for a similar problem. Just increasing buffer size is not enough, though, because the Windows Kernel does not respect it. It splits IO into 256KB chunks. This causes random IO. My solution was to set the buffer size to 4MB and to place a lock around reading such a buffer. This converted all IO to sequential IO.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to the code for this bit: "My solution was to set the buffer size to 4MB and to place a lock around reading such a buffer. This converted all IO to sequential IO."

Comment: No luck - changed the code to use the buffers between 1kB and 8MB, nothing changes, using the best case of DOP = 8, CPU remained around 25% throughout those 13 steps. Also, we are only reading 99 files with 0.6GB and this is all in cache, no physical IO is needed. The quest continues.

Comment: The ConcurrentStack part in the code is just an example, in the real application integers are tiny part of the load. My profiling showed that the majority of the real application's execution time is spent in the code shown here.

Comment: @mceda I wrote a custom stream class that coordinates with other instances of that class. All share a common lock, and they take it during read and write calls. That makes sure only one app accesses the disk at the same time. Together with a high buffer size this makes for nice, sequential IO.

Comment: Remember, a typical disk subsystem is going to give you a sustained throughput of perhaps 100 MB/sec. Maybe a little more if you have upgraded your hardware. So if your application is processing anywhere near that quickly, that's the best you'll be able to do.

Comment: We are processing in this example only 600 MB, and all of it is in the cache. Copying this folder to another one takes few seconds. Hard to believe it's IO.

Comment: May be a silly comment but have you tried other libraries that are faster at decompression?  There are some here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291895/the-fastest-gzip-decompress-library-in-net  I myself have used DotNetZip and for files over 5GB before compression I noticed about a 10 - 20% gain in decompression speed.

Comment: FWIW, The GzipStream class is a simple wrapper around a DeflateStream with an 8192 byte buffer for synchronous reads.

Comment: Awarding bounty to this answer, although it didn't help fully. The quest remains.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is usually that threads synchronize too much.

Looking for synchronization in your code I can see heavy syncing on the collections. Your threads are pushing the lines individually. This means that each line incurs at best an interlocked operation and at worst a kernel-mode lock wait. The interlocked operations will contend heavily because all threads race to get their current line into the collection. They all try to update the same memory locations. This causes cache line pinging.

Change this to push lines in bigger chunks. Push line-arrays of 100 lines or more. The more the better.

In other words, collect results in a thread-local collection first and only rarely merge into the global results.

You might even want to get rid of the manual data pushing altogether. This is what PLINQ is made for: Streaming data concurrently. PLINQ abstracts away all the concurrent collection manipulations in a well-performing way.

Comment: The only "pushing" happens at the end, after the results for the whole file are available (which in this case is equal to the number of files being 99). Or, am I missing something? I will have a look at PLINQ, thanks!

Comment: I agree, I misread the code. I'm leaving the answer anyway because it contains some useful ideas.

Comment: I fully agree with the idea, in real application we do push all the parsed lines in one batch at the end of the file processing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Parallelizing the disk reads is helping you. In fact, this could be seriously impacting your performance by creating contention in reading from multiple areas of storage at same time.

I would restructure the program to first do a single-threaded read of raw file data into a memory stream of byte[]. Then, do a Parallel.ForEach() on each stream or buffer to decompress and count the lines.

You take an initial IO read hit up front but let the OS/hardware optimize the hopefully mostly sequential reads, then decompress and parse in memory.

Keep in mind that operations like decomprless, Encoding.UTF8.ToString(), String.Split(), etc. will use large amounts of memory, so clean up references to/dispose of old buffers as you no longer need them.

I'd be surprised if you can't cause the machine to generate some serious waste hit this way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, that was already suggested, but without any improvement. The total upfront read time is completely negligible. There's something else that's preventing the full CPU usage and I am unable to detect the cause.

Comment: I think I will have to post a new question with all the suggestions from this thread applied and hope someone will spot the "bad guy" in the code. Thanks!

Comment: @mceda - Really? None of the other suggestions seemed to do this. What about shifting the decompress into the single-threaded portion? Perhaps there is some serialization going on there? One thing to try is also dumping the ConcurrentStacks. I've noticed some limiting behavior with them. You should be able to replace it with a basic Dictionary<string, byte[]> structure and pass the key to the thread lambda function. This should be reasonably safe.

Comment: "If I/O really is the bottleneck, then you might consider having a single thread that does nothing but load files and stuff them into a BlockingCollection or similar data structure so that the processing threads don't have to contend with each other for a lock on the directory." -- this is the single-read suggestion.

Comment: @mceda - Ok, missed the part at the end. If you've tried this, would you mind posting the code for that version?

Comment: I've lost count of how many different things I've tried. The latest attempts involve Concurrency Visualiser outputs and more. I will have a new question, this one has a lot of good tips, but unfortunately none helped my case directly.

Comment: @mceda - I understand that it's rather frustrating. This thread has a lot of good info in it, though. Would be a real shame to lose it and I'm not sure another question will yield different results. Unfortunately, quality on stackoverflow seems to have gone down quite a bit over the last few months as it has become much more popular.

Comment: No worries, I will try to cross-post the findings. With this one, if I change the initial questions to the latest state, most of the comments will be irrelevant. I might post a summary "attempted answer" and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem, I think, is that you are using blocking I/O, so your threads cannot fully take advantage of parallelism.

If I understand your algorithm right (sorry, I'm more of a C++ guy) this is what you are doing in each thread (pseudo-code):

```
while (there is data in the file)
    read data
    gunzip data
```

Instead, a better approach would be something like this:

```
N = 0
read data block N
while (there is data in the file)
    asyncRead data block N+1
    gunzip data block N
    N = N + 1
gunzip data block N
```

The `asyncRead` call does not block, so basically you have the decoding of block N happening concurrently with the reading of block N+1, so by the time you are done decoding block N you might have block N+1 ready (or close to be ready if I/O is slower than decoding).

Then it's just a matter of finding the block size that gives you the best throughput.

Good luck.